# Arranging $x_1,x_2,\dots x_{10},y_1,y_2,\dots y_{10}$ in such a way that they are ascending

Tags: statistics, permutations

In how many ways can $20$ letters $x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_{10},y_1,y_2, \ldots ,y_{10}$ be arranged in a line so that the suffixes of the letters $x$ and also those of the letters $y$ are respectively in ascending order of magnitude?

My Solution:

If both $x$ and $y$ have to be grouped accordingly, then this would be quite simple. But I don't think it's that simple.

From what I can deduce from this question, Any of the X can alternate with the Y as long as they're in ascending order respectively.

Can anyone guide me on what to do?

Comment: There are $20$ slots, and the arrangement is entirely determined by the location of the $x's$, so $\binom {20}{10}$...or have I misunderstood?

Comment: In fact, this problem is equivalent to painting twenty balls with two colors. So the answer is ${20 \choose 10}$

Comment: I think both of you are correct because i found a similar question to this one but that one uses n instead of 10, resulting in a formula as the answer. Perhaps one of you could elaborate more on how you reach that conclusion?